# Is it possible to retrieve the generic type used for a type token (i.e. Class<T>) at runtime?

Tags: java, class, generics, types

Neal Gafter introduced [type tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.nl/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) (for example `Class<String>`). Assuming one has access to an instance of `Class<String>` at runtime, is it possible to retrieve the generic type (`String`) at runtime?

I am looking for something similar to [Method.getGenericReturnType()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericReturnType%28%29).

Comment: not sure what you mean.  if you have the Class instance already, what more do you want?

Comment: The type used as the generic parameter.

Comment: of _what_?  a Class instance or some type name?  maybe you could add some pseudo code indicating what you are looking for...

Comment: in your question you are using "Class".  do you mean the Java class `Class`, or do you mean, "some unspecified class type"?

Comment: Of the class. In my example, that would be String as indicated in the question.

Comment: In what form do you want it?  What do you expect to be returned?  A `String` holding the class name?  If you want "the type" to be returned, the only way for that desire to make sense is...to get a `Class<String>`, which you already have.

Comment: A Type tt where System.out.println(tt) would print something like this: java.lang.String.

Comment: The only thing similar to `Method.getGenericReturnType` for a class is `Class.getGenericSuperclass()` and `Class.getGenericSuperinterfaces()`, which means you can only retrieve type information for an object that is passed into a superclass as part of that object's class declaration. Fully resolving this type information can be a pain since it can consist of TypeParameters that are scattered around your type hierarchy. See my response below for more info...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using a variation of Bob Lee's elaboration of Gafter's Gadget pattern:

```
public class GenericTypeReference<T> {

    private final Type type;

    protected GenericTypeReference() {
        Type superclass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        if (superclass instanceof Class) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Missing type parameter.");
        }
        this.type = ((ParameterizedType) superclass).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return this.type;
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // This is necessary to create a Class<String> instance
        GenericTypeReference<Class<String>> tr =
            new GenericTypeReference<Class<String>>() {};

        // Retrieving the Class<String> instance
        Type c = tr.getType();

        System.out.println(c);
        System.out.println(getGenericType(c));

    }

    public static Type getGenericType(Type c) {
        return ((ParameterizedType) c).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

}
```

The above code prints:

```
java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>
class java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is only possible for Fields/Methods. We can't get class specific generic type at runtime due to type erasure. It seems there is hack you can do if you have access to class. Read this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime).

Comment: Actually you can retrieve type information at runtime so long as it is part of a type declaration. That is what the hack refers to...

Comment: Well, I found a solution... So it is also possible for classes!

Answer (score 1):

Unlike C#, Generics don't exist at run-time in Java. So you cannot try to create an instance of generic type  or try to find type of a generic type at run-time.

Comment: Wrong, the generic information is available as metadata, otherwise, how could Method.getGenericReturnType() work?

Comment: I'm talking about some generic type T and you are talking about methods with parameter or return type with a generic type T.

Comment: Assuming a class has a method returning the generic type, it is retrievable.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is [`ParameterizedType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html).

You get these by reflecting on a `Class` and objects that come from it (`Method`, `Field`). However, you can't get a `ParameterizedType` from any old `Class` object; you can obtain one from a `Class` instance that represents a type that extends a generic class or interface.

Comment: Ok, but then, how to proceed specifically?